# how to find the weight of shortest paths in sparse matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, shortest-path

I need to find the shortest paths from a node to others node (based on the number of edges) in a sparse matrix and then calculate sum of the weights of the edges on the shortest path.
I am using scipy.sparse but I do not know how to calculate the weight of the paths.

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import shortest_path
...
graph = csr_matrix(graph)
...
dist_matrix, predecessors = shortest_path(csgraph=graph, directed=False, indices=0, return_predecessors=True)

def _get_path_length(predecessors, target):
    lngth = 1
    end = target 
    while predecessors[end] != -9999:
        lngth = 1 + lngth
        end = predecessors[end]
    return lngth

for idx, val in enumerate(lngth):
        path_length = _get_path_length(predecessors, idx)
        lngth[idx] = path_length
        path_weighs [idx] = dist_matrix[idx] / path_length
```

Comment: Do you expect us to study the `csgraph` docs and tell you?

Comment: Hi @hpaulj
I am super new in Python and I wrote a script to do it, but I am sure there should be an easy and fast solution.
My script for large graphs takes long time.